# Program to wrap text with @ symbol and quotation marks for NSDictionary and NSArray?

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

Is there a program out there that can take a text list like this:

```
cat, dog, bird
```

and output this:

```
@"cat", @"dog", @"bird"
```

I've got a long list that I'd like converted for an `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it with iOS? Read the file into a string, separate it into components, iterate over the components and write them in the format you want.

Some methods you will find useful:

```
NSString:
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error

NSArray:
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator

NSString:
+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...
```

Make your output words with something like:

```
NSString *outputWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@\"%@\"", word];
```

I don't know how "long" your list is but I have done this with the entire scrabble dictionary where the words were separated by a `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are many many text editors out there that do find and replace. (Search for ", " and replace with "", @"".) Add "@"" at the start and """ at the end and you're done.